# Is the proof of $V=U+U^\perp$ of the Cornell's teacher's handout problematic?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I just searched a [handout](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiYt9XWjKDWAhXDrJQKHXf_BRkQFghJMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.cornell.edu%2F~andreim%2FLec33.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEKF8hf5bPQjz0SiluV4cpoT6cUgg) written by the professor in Cornell. However, I feel that there is some problem in it. [image]

First, if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then if $W$ is infinite-dimensional, does $W$ necessarily have an orthonormal basis(related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426714/does-every-infinite-dimensional-inner-product-space-have-an-orthonormal-basis?noredirect=1#comment5012612_2426714))? Even if $W$ has an orthonormal basis, say $\beta$, then how can we "extend the orthnormal basis for $W$ to $V$"? Although we can choose "one" of a vector $v\in V-W$, and we know that $v\cup\beta$ is linearly independent, how can we do the Gram-Schmidt process, turning the $v\cup\beta$ to an orthonormal set? Here the $\beta$ is infinite! Does my doubt make sense? And can this proof be modified to be correct?

Comment: This is true if and only if $f|_U$ is non degenerate.

Comment: At some point in your course did your instructor say "from now on all vector spaces are finite-dimensional"?

Comment: The course is MATH 2310 at Cornell, which is introductory linear algebra. Almost certainly will all vector spaces be finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you all. Suppose if $V$ is infinite-dimesional and $U$ is finite-dimensional. Is the proof valid? It seems that the theorem itself is valid, but the proof involving take orthonormal basis for "$W$" which is again can be infinite-dimensional right?

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid for infinite-dimensional spaces. If $U$ is dense in $V$
then $U^\perp=\{0\}$, so a dense but proper subspace gives a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. "This is not valid for infinite-dimensional spaces." Do you refers to $U$ or $V$?